# Why am I getting this error when importing google font into react native expo

Tags: react-native, expo

I have this code...

```js
import React, { useCallback } from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import { useFonts } from 'expo-font'
import * as SplashScreen from 'expo-splash-screen'
import Navigation from './Navigation'
import { MaterialCommunityIcons, FontAwesome, Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons'

SplashScreen.preventAutoHideAsync()

export default () => {
    const [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        ...MaterialCommunityIcons,
        ...FontAwesome,
        ...Ionicons,
        'font-major': require('./assets/fonts/NotoSansJP-Thin.ttf'),
    });
  
    const onLayoutRootView = useCallback(async () => {
        if(fontsLoaded){
            await SplashScreen.hideAsync()
        }
    }, [fontsLoaded])
  
    if(!fontsLoaded){
        return <Text style={{marginTop: 100, fontFamily: 'font-major', fontSize: 100}}>Hey there</Text>
    }

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }} onLayout={onLayoutRootView}>
            <Text style={{marginTop: 100, fontFamily: 'font-major', fontSize: 100}}>Hey there</Text>
            <Navigation />
        </View>
    )
}
```

But I'm getting the error...

```js
fontFamily "font-major" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
    at RCTText
    at Text (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:80909:27)
    at anonymous (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:129860:44)
    at withDevTools(Anonymous) (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:129481:27)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:63105:43)
    at RCTView
    at View (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:63105:43)
    at AppContainer (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:62945:36)
    at main(RootComponent) (http://192.168.0.135:8081/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle//&platform=ios&dev=true&hot=false&lazy=true:109178:28)
```

I've tried using `Font.loadAsync` as well, nothing seems to accept this font for some reason, I've tried using other google fonts as well. I have literally no idea what I have missed.

Answer (score 2):

The font is used before it is loaded.

```js
if (!fontsLoaded){
    return <Text style={{marginTop: 100, fontFamily: 'font-major', fontSize: 100}}>Hey there</Text>
}
```

Return `null` until the custom font is loaded.

```js
if (!fontsLoaded){
    return null
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is stating what you are doing wrong. I had problems as well with the font but fixed it like so. Actually using the `Font.loadAsync({})` function the application loads the font effortlessly

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const loadFonts = async () => {
      await Font.loadAsync({
        "Poppins-Regular": require("@/assets/fonts/Poppins-Regular.ttf"),
      });
      setIsAppReady(true);
    };

    loadFonts();
  }, []);
```

I hope this helps you and feel free to ask questions!